# REGEX: How to replace four digits preceded by "w/" and "h"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following regex to replace the digits in `w/4096/h/2048` with custom values. But now I want to be able to replace any kind of four digits after `w/` and `/h`

```
imgSrc.replace('w/4096/h/2048', 'w/' + w + '/h/' + h)
```

How should I modify the code above to reflect this?

Comment: /(?:w/ )[0-9]{1,4}/
/(?:/h )[0-9]{1,4}/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[0-9]` to match a digit, and the quantifier `{4}` to match four of them:

```
imgSrc.replace('w/[0-9]{4}/h/[0-9]{4}', 'w/' + w + '/h/' + h)
```

As a short-hand for `[0-9]` you can use `\d`:

```
imgSrc.replace('w/\d{4}/h/\d{4}', 'w/' + w + '/h/' + h)
```

Comment: JS regular expression literals are not defined in quoted strings. Should be `/w\/\d{4}\/h\/\d{4}/`

Answer (score 1):

If `imgSrc` = "w/4096/h/2048", and you want to replace "4096" with "abcd", and "2048" with "efgh", try tihs:

```
var imgSrc = "w/4096/h/2048";
imgSrc.replace(new RegExp('(w/)(\\d{4})(/h/)(\\d{4})'), '$1abcd$3efgh');
```

The second line above returns the following:

```
w/abcd/h/efgh
```

Comment: Don't see a need to bother with capture groups when the captured parts are static

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` capture groups `/(\w\/)(\d+)(\/\w\/)(\d+)/`

```js
var str = "w/4096/h/2048";
var w = "123";
var h = "456"
var res = str.replace(/(\w\/)(\d+)(\/\w\/)(\d+)/
                      , "$1" + w + "$3" + h);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that had worked so far. But get a repetition of digits in some instances: `http://vrcam-10065475.image.myqcloud.com/e9a5a32f17602d2242a8.jpg?imageView2/4096/w/2048/h/2048/q/100/format/jpg`

Comment: @alex Use `(w\/)` for first capture group, `(\/\h\/)` for third capture group, `var res = str.replace(/(w\/)(\d+)(\/\h\/)(\d+)/
                      , "$1" + w + "$3" + h);`